# Send throttling process

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio, send-throttling

Wondering when the timer starts when an email is throttled at say, 250K/hr? I start the send at 8am, the system sends 250K emails over X number of minutes. Does the 60 minutes start then or when the send began?

So if it took 15 minutes to complete the first batch of sends, would the next batch start sending at 9:15ish? Or would that be when the send processing would start so we might not see the next batch get sent until around 9:30?

I know throttling isn't an exact science and the system can send slightly more/less than the selected throttle amount, but generally speaking, what's the timing look like?

Comment: So then theoretically, the first batch could finish deploying at 8:15am, depending on system resources, complexity of the email, etc., then the 2nd batch could start deploying at 9am.  In that case there would only be 30 minutes between the last of the first batch and first of the second batch.

Comment: i meant 8:30, not 8:15

Answer (score 0):

Throttles windows always start at the top of the hour